# Python CIM_DataFile search for file by full path

Tags: python, wmi

So, I am trying to write a script that will be able to connect to remote systems and query the CIM_DataFile among other things.

For the sake of testing, I wrote the following code to test on my local machine. I have two files (ns.txt and dns.txt) in the root of my C: drive, however, the queries are not working correctly for Name= (which is the full path).

```
import wmi
wmiService = wmi.WMI()
for f in wmiService.CIM_DataFile(Name="c:\ns.txt"):
    print "NAME '" + f.Name + "'"
for f in wmiService.CIM_DataFile(Name="c:\dns.txt"):
    print "NAME '" + f.Name + "'"
for f in wmiService.CIM_DataFile(FileName="ns", Extension="txt", Drive="c:"):
    print "FILENAME '" + f.Name + "'"
for f in wmiService.CIM_DataFile(FileName="dns", Extension="txt", Drive="c:"):
    print "FILENAME '" + f.Name + "'"
```

The output of the above code is:

```
NAME 'c:\ns.txt'
FILENAME 'c:\ns.txt'
FILENAME 'c:\dns.txt'
```

Why is it not showing c:\dns.txt for the Name= query? I have also tested on other files located in different places on my system and most of them do not show up for the Name= query.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the **file:wmi.py** inside the **path:Python27\Lib\site-packages**.

I changed this file.

My problem has been resolved.

In fact, the problem is with a library that is installed.